# Why console.log(error_object) outputs an error message and not its key/value pairs and methods?

Tags: javascript, try-catch

if I console.log an object, it outputs all the key/value pairs as well as its methods.

```
const obj = {
    name: "Mike",
    add : function (a, b){
       return a + b
    }
}

console.log(obj)
```

but the **error object** in try...catch block, `console.log(err)` outputs message something like "*reference error: variable is not defined*"

```
try {
   variable
}
catch(err) {
   console.log(err)
}
```

Why does it outputs message, instead of its key/value pairs and methods?

Comment: This isn't the only type of object that has this behavior, there's dates, regex, functions, node elements etc. You can use `console.dir(err)` to see the properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When catching an error using a `try...catch` block, you're dealing with an instance of one the error objects (*name*, *message*, stack*). The error object is created with the specific error information, including the `name` and `message` properties, and possibly the `stack` property.

The `err` object is an instance of [`ReferenceError`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Undefined_prop), and it contains a *message* property that describes the error message, which is `ReferenceError: variable is not defined.` This is what gets logged when you call `console.log(err)`.

If you want to access other properties and methods of error objects, you can do so explicitly. For example, you can log the *name* and *stack* properties like this:

```
console.log(err.name);
console.log(err.stack);
```

Answer (score 4):

The underlying conversion of arguments into console messages for `console.log()` does not have to always print out the key-value pairs of object and varies from environment to environment.

For example, the [`console`](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#consolelogdata-args) object in NodeJS uses [`util.format()`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#utilformatformat-args) to perform the conversion, and that in turn calls [`util.inspect()`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#utilinspectobject-options) to format object, which treats `Error` objects differently to normal objects. I'm not sure about the specifics for other browsers, however, but they probably also treat `Error` objects differently as well to aid debugging.

Does this answer your question?